# [connectycube]Specifying Android Camera for local stream

Tags: android, android-camera, connectycube

I am using the Android SDK to connect connectycube. But I have multiple cameras on my Android board. Is there a way for me to specify which camera to use to display my local video stream when establishing a connection? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the Connectycube Android SDK doesn't support the setting `deviceId` before starting the call. The SDK automatically selects the first front camera and uses it. You can switch the camera after starting the call only.

As an option, you can try to create your own camera capturer via extending the `RTCBaseVideoCapturer` and setting it as source capturer https://developers.connectycube.com/android/videocalling?id=_3-set-rtcscreencapturer-as-current-video-capturer

But pay attention it is not a checked solution and you may need to realize main functionality (such as camera switching, audio/video muting, etc) by yourself.